# How to put read more at the end of paragraph?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this code pen link https://codepen.io/alexfranka/pen/oLmNyp

**Here the read more link is done like this:**

```
<p><a class="readmore" href="#">Show more (+)</a>
```

There is just an opening p tag and there is no closing `p` tag.

I tried putting the link after "semper suscipit, posuere a, pede." But when I clicked the link it didn't work

How do I remake the code so it works?

Answer (score 0):

Because in the javascript you do

```
$(this).parent().prev(".more-content").toggleClass("cg-visible");
```

Where `$(this)`refers to the link clicked. If you put it inside a different parent, then this line doesn't find the correct `.more-content` element you want.

Even worse, its parent doesn't have a closing tag so the html isn't even valid.

Comment: ok. where can i find an example that has what i need? i searched a lot. all i could find was examples in which the read more link is at the next line and there are examples that use ...

Comment: You haven't explained what you need at all. Edit the question's body to tell us what you exactly want to happen, so people can properly help.